# How can I get/query data from a table in Google Spreadsheets and limit to the first X rows for each "set" of rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data (example below) that represents multiple sets of data. I want to get all the sets but limit each set to the first X rows.

I know how to use the `limit` function of `query` but that seems to limit for all the rows.

## Example Data

| app ID | app name | l1 manager | target score | amount to drop by score | dimension name | dimension value | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 10 | 1 | 35 | 3.50 |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 10 | 2 | 9 | 0.90 |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 10 | 3 | 15 | 1.50 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 70 | 1 | 50 | 0.71 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 70 | 2 | 22 | 0.31 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 70 | 3 | 30 | 0.43 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 67 | 1 | 45 | 0.67 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 67 | 2 | 18 | 0.27 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 67 | 3 | 50 | 0.75 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 30 | 1 | 19 | 0.63 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 30 | 2 | 41 | 1.37 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 30 | 3 | 13 | 0.43 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 17 | 1 | 1 | 0.06 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 17 | 2 | 38 | 2.24 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 17 | 3 | 16 | 0.94 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 73 | 1 | 48 | 0.66 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 73 | 2 | 38 | 0.52 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 73 | 3 | 24 | 0.33 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 0.63 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 0.38 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 8 | 3 | 36 | 4.50 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 56 | 1 | 16 | 0.29 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 56 | 2 | 44 | 0.79 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 56 | 3 | 41 | 0.73 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 55 | 1 | 6 | 0.11 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 55 | 2 | 50 | 0.91 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 55 | 3 | 43 | 0.78 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 30 | 1 | 13 | 0.43 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 30 | 2 | 29 | 0.97 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 30 | 3 | 25 | 0.83 |

Each `app ID` is one set.

I can sort on `app ID` and `dimension value` like so: `=QUERY(A14:H44, "SELECT * ORDER BY A, G")`.

In this example, I only want it to return the first **2 rows** for each `app ID`/set. So the expected output would be like:

| app ID | app name | l1 manager | target score | amount to drop by score | dimension name | dimension value | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 10 | 2 | 9 | 0.90 |
| 1 | one | a | 49 | 10 | 3 | 15 | 1.50 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 70 | 2 | 22 | 0.31 |
| 2 | two | a | 32 | 70 | 3 | 30 | 0.43 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 67 | 2 | 18 | 0.27 |
| 3 | three | a | 46 | 67 | 1 | 45 | 0.67 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 30 | 3 | 13 | 0.43 |
| 4 | four | a | 43 | 30 | 1 | 19 | 0.63 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 17 | 1 | 1 | 0.06 |
| 5 | five | b | 38 | 17 | 3 | 16 | 0.94 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 73 | 3 | 24 | 0.33 |
| 6 | six | b | 37 | 73 | 2 | 38 | 0.52 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 0.38 |
| 7 | seven | b | 36 | 8 | 1 | 5 | 0.63 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 56 | 1 | 16 | 0.29 |
| 8 | eight | b | 45 | 56 | 3 | 41 | 0.73 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 55 | 1 | 6 | 0.11 |
| 9 | nine | c | 44 | 55 | 3 | 43 | 0.78 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 30 | 1 | 13 | 0.43 |
| 10 | ten | c | 37 | 30 | 3 | 25 | 0.83 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach **`(not query-based)`** you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(A1:H1,sort(unique(tocol(A2:A,1))),lambda(a,c,iferror(vstack(a,array_constrain(sort(filter(A:H,A:A=c),7,1),2,8)))))
```

- *`array_constrain` is used here to set the **limit** as `2 rows * 8 columns` which you may change accordingly*
- *`sort` is used to ascend both column_1 `A` & column_7 `G`*

[image]

Comment: This works. I went through the function to figure out what it is doing. Mind if I edit your question to break down the answer with more help details (for posteristy sake)?

Answer (score 1):

Old-school approach using a conditional count of 'App ID' by row:

```
={A1:H1;filter(A2:H,countifs(A2:A,A2:A,row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A))<=2)}
```

N.B. Your question says you want the first two rows per App ID, but your example answer appears to have the last two rows. You can flip the `"<="` for a `">="` to account for either possibility.

Comment: I am sorry. I was not clear in the question. In the output, I want data sorted on `dimension value` and then the first two rows.